# WaitForSingleObject always returning WAIT_TIMEOUT in secondary thread

Tags: c, winapi, io, pthreads

This problem occurs in a multi-threaded application (two threads).
It seems to occurs on Windows only in a very specific configuration - more details on that later.
The program is written in C and uses the pthreads library.
It is is essentially a command-line interpreter.

The main thread spawns a "reader" thread that executes a function that is responsible for reading user input text line by line from the standard input and queuing the line read.

The main thread dequeues the line, interpret and executes the corresponding commands.

The problem is in the "reader" thread.

```c
HANDLE stdin_handle;
DWORD wait_result;

stdin_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
if (stdin_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  return ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
if (stdin_handle == NULL) {
  return ERROR_NULL_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

do {
  wait_result = WaitForSingleObject(stdin_handle, 100);
  /* omitted: verify some condition here, break from loop if satisfied */
}
while(wait_result == WAIT_TIMEOUT);
```

The calls to `WaitForSingleObject` "reader" thread always return `WAIT_TIMEOUT` when the program is run in some specific configurations.

**Configuration where the problem occurs**:

- the program is run in git bash, without redirection (input direct from keyboard)

**Configurations where the does not problem occur**:

- the program is run in git bash under Windows, with stdin redirected from a file
- the program is run within gdb, without redirection (input direct from keyboard)
- the program is run in CMD or Powershell, without redirection (input direct from keyboard)

I have read the `synchapi.h` API documentation but could not find the information I need to solve this issue.

Comment: wait on stdin_handle is initial error

Comment: Could you please explain your answer @RbMm? Why would that be an error? Is there a relevant part of the official online documentation addressing this issue?

Comment: in case input is redirected - wait on file is error always. and for what you wait at all ? you can simply use `ReadFile` in asynchronous mode as example

Comment: I edited the code snippet to answer your question. Btw, I do not have an error reported by WaitForSingleObject in case input is redirected from a file.

Comment: yes, will be no formal error, because WaitForSingleObject let wait on file handle too, however this is wrong by sense

Comment: Maybe related: [Win32 - read from stdin with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955617/)

Comment: Why not just use fgets and sit there waiting for input instead of WaitForSingleObject? Alternatively use _kbhit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the tip, I will have a look at it.

Comment: @cup Because I need the thread to check some condition periodically, it cannot sit there waiting for input. _kbhit looks promising.

Comment: Eventually, I got this to work by using POSIX primitives and by compiling under MINGW. This is not an intellectually satisfying outcome though, as other parts of the program still use WINAPI.

Comment: @dde Why not just do the user input in one thread and the other stuff in another thread?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because the condition is used here to end the reader thread.

Comment: @dde that doesn't change what I said. The reader thread could wait on the console input and a CreateEvent object at the same time, and another thread could signal the event when the reader should stop

Comment: I understand I could change the code to take better benefit of WinAPI, using, e.g., WaitForMultipleObjects. But the main issue here is that the thread does not receive an event when input is given on the console (depending on the console...)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer: just posting this as an example of what I was saying in my comment.  Could you do something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct Info
{
    std::atomic<bool> running;
};

void one_seconder(Info* info)
{
    for (int ii = 0; info->running; ++ii)
    {
        std::cout << ii << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    }
    std::cout << "Out of thread" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    Info info;
    char ch;

    // Start thread
    info.running = true;
    std::thread tobj(one_seconder, &info);

    std::cout << "Type any character and hit return" << std::endl;
    // Alternatively #include <conio.h> and use _getch();
    std::cin >> ch;
    info.running = false;
    std::cout << "Terminating" << std::endl;

    // Wait for thread to terminate
    tobj.join();

    std::cout << "Exit" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```